# Tuple swap with indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, tuples

I'm trying to swap positions of elements in this array with a tuple swap and `indexOf()`

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

should equal:  `[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

```
[ array1[array1.indexOf(3)], array1[array1.indexOf(4)] ] = 

[ array1[array1.indexOf(4)], array1[array1.indexOf(3)] ]
```

the evaluated result is simply the swapped elements and not the array itself..

```
[4, 3]
```

How can I get the whole array back?

Comment: `array1` ? ... ...

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using destructuring assignment to swap elements but it will work in this case because the `array.indexOf(4)` is changed to `2`. So after the first assignment array looks like.

```
[1,2,4,4,5,6,7,8]
```

In the second assignment the the `indexOf(4)` returns `2`. So you change the second element again to `3`. So the array looks same.

The line is same as

```
array1[array1.indexOf(3)] = array1[array1.indexOf(4)] // array become [1,2,4,4,5,6,7,9]
array1[array1.indexOf(4)] = array1[array1.indexOf(3)] //here  indexOf(4) is `2`
```

See the below snippet

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];

[arr[1],arr[console.log(arr[1]) || 5]] = ['changed',3]
```

So you for the second element the first element is already changed.

You should store the index in variable and then use it.

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let ind = array1.indexOf(3);
array1[array1.indexOf(4)] = 3;
array1[ind] = 4
console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const index1 = array1.indexOf(3);
const index2 = array1.indexOf(4);

[ array1[index1], array1[index2] ] = [ array1[index2], array1[index1] ];
```

**Demo:**

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log('array1 before: ', array1);

const index1 = array1.indexOf(3);
const index2 = array1.indexOf(4);

[ array1[index1], array1[index2] ] = [ array1[index2], array1[index1] ];

console.log('array1 after: ',array1);
```

Comment: This works, but I'm trying to simulate a problem where you don't necessarily know the index. You would only know the value and then derive the index of the array

Answer (score 0):

You can use array map function and check the index. `map` will return a new array

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let newArray = array1.map(function(item, index) {
  if (index === 2) {
    return array1[index + 1]
  } else if (index === 3) {
    return array1[index - 1]
  } else {
    return item
  }

})

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: is there any way to do this using the tuple swap method? Am I not simply assigning the corresponding elements in the this array to new values?

Comment: There is almost no reason to loop through whole array just to swap two values. Its clear from post OP wants to swap on the bases of value not on the basis of index.Hope you got it.

Comment: And if you considered the OP wants to swap indexes then why not `[arr[2],arr[3]] = [arr[3],arr[2]]`

Comment: @MaheerAli so that is the reason of down voting? and you asking me to believe indexOf does not loop ?

Comment: This is a valid answer. @MaheerAli two `indexOf` are hardly better than one map. Just FYI.

Comment: For more reference on why `indexOf` is actually slower: https://medium.com/@mrashes2/indexof-vs-for-loop-6a9f7bd5c646

Comment: @Akrion You are right in the part that running two `indexOf` is not better than `map()`. For that there could be same function get the indexes. But the question here is not about performance. And neither the code of the answer is correct OP didn't asked to swap indexes he asked to swap the values.

Comment: @MaheerAli it is not swaping the index but the content of index. You can swap index in array?

Comment: @brk I mean that OP don't want to swap content. He want to swap `3` and `4` in the array.(indexes are not given...)